# Laravel 5 success validator missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple `laravel 5` code that adds commodities and works well, however the success validation won't show up. Here is the code:

**commodityController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Commodity;

class CommodityController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = \Validator::make(\Request::all(),
          ['name' => 'required|unique:commodities,name'],
          ['price' => 'required']
        );

        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            $com = new Commodity;

            $com->name        = \Request::input('name', 'Test');
            $com->price       = \Request::input('price', '0.00');
            $com->description = \Request::input('description', 'desc');

            $com->save();

            return \View::make('pages.admin.commodity.add')->with('message', 'Commodity Added!');
        } else {
            return \View::make('pages.admin.commodity.add')->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }
    }
}
```

**add.blade.php**

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          {{Session::get('message')}}
      </div>
  @endif

  @if ($errors -> has())
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          @foreach($errors -> all() as $error)        
              {{$error}} <br />
          @endforeach
      </div>
  @endif
```

The addition of data works but the success validation won't show up in the blade. Also, the error validation works. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your rules in a single array:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(\Request::all(), [
    'name'  => 'required|unique:commodities,name',
    'price' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the pros of passing rules in a single array?

Comment: It's the only way to do it. The way you did it is invalid. The `price` wasn't being required.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by redirecting.

Instead of 
`return \View::make('pages.admin.commodity.add')->with('message', 'Commodity Added!');`

I used `return redirect('commodities/add')->with('message', 'Commodity Added!');`